# How can I make a list of files in a directory where the files in that directory are first before files in subdirectories in python?

Tags: python, list, file, directory, subdirectory

I'm trying to make a list of files, using recursion, in a given directory. I have been able to do this correctly but the order of my list is not correct. I need the files on the most surface layer of the directory show first in the list with the other files in subdirectories being in lexicographical order after.

Here is the code I have to do what I've discussed above.

```
import os
important = []
def search_directory(folder):
     hold = os.listdir(folder)
     for i in hold:
          test = os.path.join(folder, i)
          if os.path.isfile(test) == True and 
               os.path.isfile(test) not in interesting:
               interesting.append(test)
          else:
               search_directory(test)
     return important
```

Comment: Any code you can share? Seems like you are just appending to the wrong end.

Comment: Just added the code that I have that is searching through and making the list, hope this helps.

Comment: You need to change the tree traverse. Look up in_order pre_order and post_order traversal. The code change to give the ordering you want should then be straightforward for you. You change where the recursive call sits relative to the 'if'

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need BFS traversal of your directory tree.

```
import collections
import os

def extract_tree(root):

    q = collections.deque()
    q.append(root)
    
    tree = []
    while q:
        
        root = q.popleft()
        contents = sorted(os.listdir(root))
        for f in contents:
            path = os.path.join(root, f)
            if os.path.isfile(path):
                tree.append(path)
            else:
                q.append(path)
                
    return tree
```